# Customize background repeat without actually editing the source

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for HTML page which I use only for top part of the page.So when I gave repeat-x, the header content part of the image was too lengthy that it came out of the actual header content of the page.Is there a way to make it confine to only the header part that depending on it's height more or less(increase or decrease only the top part(required part) of background image when used). Also if there is a background-image that has a plain color, how to get the color code of that, so that I can background-color property instead of background. The URL of the page is http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/fotofolium/ & I would like to reduce the height of black color in header part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background position To make the black portion thinner. And the end color of your gradient is **#325e00**. You can add this color on background to get full gradient.

```
body {
        background: url("images/wrapper-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -35px #335F01;
        color: #333333;
        font-family: 'Arvo',serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the color(end or other) in a background-image.Is there any tool to capture color & give it's code.

Comment: I just saved that background image of ur website & picked the end color of the gradient using Photoshop color picker tool.

Answer (score 0):

Set background not for (i'm assuming) the `<body>` tag but set it for the header. Using the CSS `background` shorthand property like this:

```
header {background:#ffffff url('img.png') repeat-x right top;}
```

Here you can specify the default background-color (here #ffffff) AND the background-image.